# Reserve physical memory for memory mapped files in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, lucene, mmap, pmap

I am using Lucene's MMapDirectory to keep index files in memory mapped files. According to the output of pmap command, only part of these files actually reside in the physical memory. I would like to put more RAM to the server and make sure that the all files are completely in the memory. However, the extra RAM will be proportionally distributed. In a Linux system, can I reserve some physical memory specifically for these files (which are about 5GB in total).

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there aren't any decent out-of-the-box solutions available at the moment.

You could use `RAMDirectory` which is closest to what you are looking for, but it is not efficient (too much ram gets allocated, GC slowness, etc.). There's [LUCENE-3659](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3659) to improve this, but it's not ready yet.

You could look at ramfs/tmpfs, but both of them are volatile (index goes away after switching the machine off), also you could end up in situations where [RAM gets cached in another RAM](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/use-MMapDirectory-with-tmpfs-td4096943.html).

More info:
http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/07/use-lucenes-mmapdirectory-on-64bit.html